# Is there a good way to cache apt and pip packages on my home network without changes to my clients?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip, apt

I am testing and building a lot of containers over a somewhat slow internet connection. Every time I test a rebuild it has to re-download all the apt and pip packages.

I have seen a couple solutions to cache locally with docker, but I need the build process to work for other developers and also during deploy.

I have also found a number of solutions to caching apt and pip with a local server, but all of them require changes to the clients which also won't work for me.

Is there a way I can set up a router level DNS redirect to a local package caching server, or a similar solution?

Also, in the hopes to avoid the XY problem, is there a better solution I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: The single most important thing at a pure Docker level is to make sure you `RUN pip install` before you `COPY` files other than the `setup.cfg`/`setup.py`/`requirements.txt` file: if you `COPY` a file into the image that's changed it will cause all `RUN` steps after it to be repeated.  Do you have a sample Dockerfile that illustrates the problem?

Comment: My problem is I am basically doing QA on docker files, so I'll make a small change and then watch it build. In general the docker files run apt update, install apt packages, copy pip requirements, install requirements, run test suite. Also I can't just use a base image because too many projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
apt update && apt install -y python3.8 ...
```

and

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

to the Dockerfile and that made the process much less painful.